# Copy CSV with fewer columns than PostgreSQL table?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have a table like this following:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a 
(
  cola text,
  colb text,
  colc text,
  cold text,
  cole text
)
```

Currently, I am loading the table with the following:

```
\copy table_a from PATH/TO/CSV/CSV_FILE.csv DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

where `CSV_FILE.csv` also has all 5 columns: `cola`, `colb`, `colc`, `cold`, `cole`.

But what if I have `CSV_FILE_2.csv` that only has `cola`, `colb`, `colc`?

I want to be able to do something like:

```
\copy table_a from PATH/TO/CSV/CSV_FILE_2.csv DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

to insert new rows from `CSV_FILE_2.csv` but leaves `cold` and `cole` null.

But when I try to do the above, I get a

```
ERROR:  missing data for column "cold"
```

Is there an efficient way to use the `copy` command to just add the new rows from `CSV_FILE_2.csv`?

One workaround I thought of is insert the rows into a temporary table, insert the rows from the temporary table into `table_a` and then delete the temporary table, but that seems cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual page for the `\copy` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY) only gives a brief overview of the syntax, and doesn't separate the "copy from" and "copy to" options, but does say this:

> The syntax of this command is similar to that of the SQL COPY command. All options other than the data source/destination are as specified for COPY.

If we look up [the manual page for `COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) instead, we see a clearer synopsis of the `COPY FROM` version:

> COPY table_name [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ] FROM { 'filename' | PROGRAM 'command' | STDIN } [ [ WITH ] ( option [, ...] ) ] [ WHERE condition ]

Notably, this includes a column list, which is explained below:

> For COPY FROM, each field in the file is inserted, in order, into the specified column. Table columns not specified in the COPY FROM column list will receive their default values.

This sounds like exactly what you're looking for (the default value for a nullable column being `null`, if not otherwise specified). So in your example, you would run:

```
\copy table_a (cola, colb, colc) from 'PATH/TO/CSV/CSV_FILE_2.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: Thanks, yes you're correct. This works for me by specifying the column names. I would have thought that by default if you don't specify any column names it would default to something functionality equivalent to specifying (cola, colb, colc) but it did not!